# How to drop a pronoun? (pronoun-dropping/removing 'I'/omitting the subject)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I wrote resume and got stuck in this place. There are recommendations to write your achievements in the short form (without "I"):

"Worked with ... "
 "Created something ... "
 "Collaborated with ... "

At first I wrote my resume as:

"Have created ..."
"Was responsible for ..."
"Created something ..."

Then I found out that people don't write it in such style (Am I right?).
There are three questions:

1) How can I omit "I" in the prefect tense and in the continuous tense.

2) Does this sentence "I bought potato and cooked it" work as "I have cooked potato"? (Because "cooking food" doesn't guarantee result. As I understand there is a perfect tense for this purpose.)

3) As alternative, is it correct to mix sentences as:

"I have created ..."
"Created something ..."
"Collaborated with ... "
"I was responsible for ..."

Comment: Dropping pronouns like that is not grammatical, but you might be talking about creating *headlines* (cf. newspapers). For CV style, this may be on-topic at [TheWorkplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) (note: *reviewing* the CV is off-topic there).

Comment: @Lawrence, to be honest, it's not only about CV, I have the same problem if I leave comments for code in my version control program. If I leave small comments with "I have added", "I corrected" then all my history looks like "I"-"I"-"I"-"I". At present I found out that CV is a good example:
[example 1](http://www.allresumescv.com/resume-work-experience-examples.html/resume-work-experience-examples-7),
[example 2](http://www.job-interview-site.com/22-top-resume-achievements-examples-of-achievements-in-resumes.html),
How can it be "not grammatical", if people, including natives, use it in CV?

Comment: For resumes, I don't see full sentences used. Instead of "I was supervisor of six people" and "I was commended for project X" I normally see "Supervised six people" and Commended for Project X" used. Similarly for commenting code, I see "2017.01.25: reformatted output per user reqeust" with the coder's initials following.